# How can my smart contract swap WETH for ETH?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

My smart contract receives WETH. I want to create a function anyone can run to convert the WETH into ETH.

That's the code I have

```
function swapWeth() public nonReentrant {
   uint balanceWETH = IWETH(WETH).balanceOf(address(this));

   if (balanceWETH > 0) {
      IERC20(WETH).approve(address(this), balanceWETH);
      IWETH(WETH).withdraw(balanceWETH);
   }
}
```

When I call the function I always get the following message and my transaction never goes through.

> We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the
> contract and this transaction may fail.

How do I debug this?

I just want to call the `withdraw` function of the WETH smart contract to swap my contracts's WETH into ETH. The user initiating the transaction just pays for the gas fee.

I just want to convert my contract's WETH into ETH.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit**:
I changed the code to this and it still fails. I'm on Goerli. Does someone has a working example?

```
  function withdrawETH() public {
    address WETH9 = 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6; // Goerli
    uint balanceWETH = IERC20(WETH9).balanceOf(address(this));
    IWETH9(WETH9).withdraw(balanceWETH);
  }
```

Contract address: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xd9e84819483410b08ec24320eb88acfc4ee6e8c8

**Edit**: See Petr's response and comments bellow. The problem was with my 'receive' function

Comment: this error happens when you pass a wrong argument to the function

Comment: but my function doesn't have any arguments

Comment: inside function you are calling too many functions. metamask makes static calls to determine the gas fee. https://betterprogramming.pub/sending-static-calls-to-a-smart-contract-with-ethers-js-e2b4ceccc9ab

Comment: But I call just two functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IERC20(WETH).approve(address(this), balanceWETH);
```

This line gives approval

- from your contract address - that's the address that calls the `approve()` function
- to your contract address - first param, value `address(this)`

---

The approval is given by the address that executes the `approve()` function.

If you want to get approval from the user, they need to invoke the `approve()` function directly on the `WETH` contract in a separate transaction - not through your contract.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if I needed this line at all. I just want the contract to be able to convert its own WETH

Comment: @koxon Then you don't need this line. Other common reason why your `swapWeth()` may revert: Incorrect WETH contract address - usually because your contract is on a different network than the WETH contract. In that case, the call to `balanceOf()` already causes the revert.

Comment: I removed the approval.
I want to use the Goerli WETH9 contract: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6 
But my transactions still fail on the balanceOf apparently: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x51fe74c8d47a57604033f0cb88272d64ef00ca67704716bc0cf31b74f3dce130#internal
I'm connected to Goerli using Remix IDE.

Comment: @koxon Can you verify the linked contract on Etherscan? It's much easier to troubleshoot with code available.

Comment: Thanks Petr. I uploaded a new contract and verified it. Contract: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xd9e84819483410b08ec24320eb88acfc4ee6e8c8 
See the withdrawETH() function. The contract has 0.01 WETH. I have two failed transactions there. Is it a gas issue? I don't know how to debug this. Error has no details.

Comment: @koxon When the WETH contract calls `msg.sender.transfer(wad);`, it executes the `receive()` function in your contract. You can only spend 2300 gas in this function (see the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#receive-ether-function)) but your function is trying to spend more by assigning 2 storage values... You should be able to resolve this by removing the `x = 2; y = msg.value;` from your `receive()` function... Debugger of the tx: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/goerli/0x5add31dfa699cc29d720f8efce51b62cb14f23946d7b20449c375c7f469ea6f7/debugger?trace=0.1.0.0

Comment: Thank you so much Petr! I copied this receive() function from somewhere and I had a feeling it was an issue. Thank you for the debugger link as well. You're the man!